# Missing 'ad content' Parameter in Google Analytics 4: How to Retrieve and Export

Tags: google-bigquery, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I've noticed that the 'content' parameter has seemingly disappeared from Google Analytics 4 (GA4). While it's visible in the Explore section, the high level of sampling makes it less useful for my analysis. I'm looking for insights on where this dimension went and how to export it into the raw table when transferring data from GA4 to BigQuery. Currently, I can only see 'name,' 'medium,' and 'source.'

I attempted to set up a custom dimension to track UTMs, but it's not working as expected. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and if so, what solutions or workarounds have you found? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Details:

I've verified that the 'content' parameter is visible in the Explore section of GA4 but is not present in the raw table.
The high level of sampling in the Explore section hinders its usefulness for my analysis.
I tried creating a custom dimension to track UTMs, but it's not functioning as desired.
I'm specifically looking for insights or solutions related to the disappearance of the 'content' parameter in GA4 and how to export it to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this GA4 demention [image]

Comment: Hello Mykola , thank you for your answear. That is exactly what I am saying, that I do not have this dimension in GA4 anymore.

Comment: This dimension is available in the explorer section.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but because of sampling I am not using GA4 anymore. Rather extracting data to BigQuery and then analyzing there. But sadly 'content' dimension does not exists in raw table from GA4 and I am wondering how to solve this, because this dimension is really useful. :) Thanks!

Comment: Well then that's not all. It was simply "low hanging fruit."
You can create a custom dimension in analytics and send "conten"t as an event parameter (for example, "page view"). Parameter data can be retrieved using Javascript. https://gist.github.com/bjornpagen/bcea5037d61dc29b218cc00a20f5f327

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This dimension is available in the explorer section